# Is it possible to select a select in SQL without making a nvarchar variable?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
--This table has a list of columns I need from #testTableTwo
CREATE TABLE #testTableOne
(
    id  nvarchar(250)
)

--This column has the values I need. I just don't know which columns I want.
CREATE TABLE #testTableTwo
(
    one INT,
    two INT,
    three INT,
    four int
)



INSERT INTO #testTableOne VALUES ('one'),('two'),('three')
INSERT INTO #testTableTwo VALUES (1,2,3,4)
    SELECT (SELECT * FROM #testTableOne) FROM #testTableTwo
```

So what I want this to be is:

```
SELECT ONE, TWO, THREE FROM #testTableTwo
```

Is this possible? I know I can make a nvarchar and do some stuff with COALESCE, but I'm trying to avoid that. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What end result are you looking for here?

Comment: It is possible(because it is a select * statement) but what result from the query do you want

Comment: I have a table that has the columns I need to query from another table. So I want to get the list of columns from one table, and then get those columns from a different table..

Comment: No, you can't do that (dynamic sql) without building and executing a string.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use dynamic SQL like this.

```
-- First construct the fields list
DECLARE @fields varchar(500)
SET @fields = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + #testTableOne.id
                FROM #testTableOne
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
            , 1, 2, '')

-- Next construct the actual SQL statement
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@fields+' FROM #testTableTwo'

-- And last but not least run it.
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: +1: Perfect answer, but I would go the route of `Select @fields = Coalesce(@fields + ',','') + t.id From #testTableOne` for the variable population simply because with the `FOR XML PATH` solution you can run into issues if there are certain characters ('<','>','"',etc) in your column name. I've run into this before with the `FOR XML PATH` solution. Most of the time it is perfect and in some scenarios it can do what the `COALESCE` can't, but since it's a straight variable population it is safer.

Comment: Good code, but OP wanted to do it *without* building a string (which I know is impossible, but maybe your answer should be more explicit about that?)

Comment: I've used that method before too, but I've run into problems with very long strings where it cut off the combind string after a couple of thousand characters.

Comment: I could see that too, with sp_executeSQL I don't think there is a limit so I would imagine and Nvarchar(Max) would be safe for the variable, but a LEFT or something like that could give you issues if you wanted to do more manipulation, but yeah, I see your point. Good answer.

Comment: No I mean that I got the truncation after the  *Select @fields = Coalesce(@fields + ',','') + t.id From #testTableOne*.  Once I was able to generate the string at the correct length I was able to use the sp_executesql without a problem. :)